# jQuery datepicker: preselect month of second datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, datepicker

I have two datepickers: arrival and departure. Now if one selects the 26th April in arrival, the departure datepicker should be preselected to the April (currently it would be March). So how could I implement this?

I tried the following:

```
$( "#arrival" ).datepicker({
    buttonImage: 'fileadmin/templates/images/calendar.png',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOn: 'both',
    buttonText: 'arrival',
    onSelect: function(){
        var arrivalDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate').getDate();
        var arrivalMonth = $(this).datepicker('getDate').getMonth();
        var arrivalYear = $(this).datepicker('getDate').getFullYear();
        $('#departure').datepicker({ defaultDate: new Date(arrivalYear,arrivalMonth,01) });
    }
});
$( "#departure" ).datepicker({
    buttonImage: 'fileadmin/templates/images/calendar.png',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOn: 'both',
buttonText: 'departure'
});
```

`setDate` would fill out the text input field which is not desired. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

Currently in your `onSelect` callback you're attempting to reinitialize the `departure` element in order to change its `defaultDate` option:

```
$('#departure').datepicker({ defaultDate: new Date(arrivalYear,arrivalMonth,01) });
```

However, after initialization, the `datePicker` options should be set in this form, *without re-initializing* the element:

```
datePicker('option','some-option','some-option-value').
```

**Solution**

Use the correct form to set the `defaultDate` option of the `depature` element.

For example:

```
...
var departure_date = new Date(arrivalYear,arrivalMonth,01);
$('#departure').datepicker('option','defaultDate', departure_date);
...
```

See **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B2LRq/)**

Answer (score 0):

first caluculate the value then set like this

```
$( "#departure" ).val($("#arrival").val())datepicker(
 ......

);
```

Comment: What is the difference between `val` and `setDate`? Both seems to do the same.

Comment: i dont know the reason exactly.I used like this

Comment: This seems to set the input field. What I want to do is that in the second datepicker the month should be already on April (like the first one) when he clicks on the datepicker and choose a date. So no directly setting of the value - only selecting the month.

Comment: With the code I tried the input field is already filled out. I don't know what the user wants to select. So the user had to click again on the datepicker to choose the right date?